# Characterization of strongly transitive monoid actions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions, monoid

Let $M\curvearrowright X$ be a monoid action. Say it's *strongly transitive* if it has only one strong orbits, i.e if $\forall x,y\exists m\in M:mx=y$.

Page 5 of [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/2c1a/b91e10e336edeef6301d6dac1d0afabaafce.pdf) says that if $M$ is finite, then itself as an $M$-set is strongly transitive iff it's a group.

What goes wrong if $M$ isn't finite?

**Added.** More interestingly, let $f:A\to B$ be a monoid homomorphism. Let $\operatorname{Ker}f\curvearrowright A$ be the canonical multiplicative action of the kernel. Are the following equivalent?

1. The connected components of $\operatorname{Ker}f\curvearrowright A$ are strongly connected;
2. $A$ is a group.

**Update.** I realized it is completely unreasonable to expect the property of being a group to be captured by a single homomorphism out of it. I would like to update my question to the following:

For a monoid homomorphism $f:A\to B$ let $\operatorname{Ker}f\curvearrowright A$ be the canonical multiplicative action of the kernel. Are the following equivalent?

1. The connected components of $\operatorname{Ker}f\curvearrowright A$ are strongly connected *for all* $f$;
2. $A$ is a group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is ok for infinite monoids too.  If $a\in M$, then $ba=1$ for some $b\in M$ and $cb=1$ for some $c\in M$.  So $c=cba=a$ and hence $b$ and $a$ are inverses.  My paper you quoted is about finite monoids but that doesn't mean that the assumption is always needed.

The answer to your second question is no. Take $B$ to be the monoid $0,1$ with multiplication and take $A$ to be the result of adjoining an identity $1$ to any non-empty semigroup. Take your homomorphism to take 1
 to 1 and all other elements to 0.

Comment: Sorry for bugging you again, but I realize that $A$ being a group cannot possibly be captured by a single homomorphism out of it. What if we ask the components of $\operatorname{Ker}f\curvearrowright A$ to be strongly connected for all $f$?

Comment: If you take f to be the homomorphism collapsing A to a point then you are back to the original question of A acting on A so back to a group.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm not understanding incorrectly - the answer to my updated question is then 'yes', correct?

Comment: Yes  it is the same as the original.